# Force control to stay beside another

Tags: c#, wpf

I am in the process of completing a fault logger for my company.
Unfortunately, not all people have the same screen resolution (ranging from 800 - 1080), I need to create controls that can change size based on the window size.

So far, I have been able to force controls to change their dimensions based on window dimensions, but I am faced with a challenge of them overlapping after a certain size, as shown below:

[image: Normal window]

[image: Re sized controls]

Is there a way to force the TextBox and GroupBox to float just left of the DataGrid, so it will move right based on the width of the grid?

Comment: when you got a control there are circles and arrows on the sides this are the anchors use that

Comment: You have to set Anchor of the left control to Left, then it will not move into the other one.

Comment: As it is WPF, cant you place the controls in a grid? e.g. the left controls in the column 0 and the right controls in column 1?

Comment: @MPatel, your answer worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid columns will solve the overlap problem but you might want to consider using a GridSplitter control, for example:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  <ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="Black" 
          ShowsPreview="True"
          Width="5"
          />
```

References & useful pages:

- ["GridSplitter Class (System.Windows.Controls)"  [msdn.microsoft.com]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.aspx)
- [Bing Search: 'gridsplitter'](http://www.bing.com/search?q=gridsplitter&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC)